# Change binding if value is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to change binding if the value is null or empty.

I make this exemple to explain :

```
List<test> list = new List<test>();
list.Add(new test { Name1 = "Bill", Name2 = "Jack" });
list.Add(new test { Name1 = "", Name2 = "Adam" });
TestDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name1}" />
```

in this case will show :

```
Bill

""
```

I want if the first name is null or empty will show the `Name2`, then

```
Bill

Adam
```

in another way I want to do :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="if({Binding Name1} == null)
                                  {Binding Name2} else {Binding Name1}   " />
```

**edit**

I thing that Converter resolve that, but I can't send the `Name2` to change the value if the `Name1` is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a new property:

```
public string Name { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name1) ? Name2 : Name1; } }

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) could be used for this. It attempts multiple bindings until one succeeds. A converter that returns [UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx) is considered a failed binding, so you could use one such as:

```
public class EmptyToUnsetConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

And apply it to each binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Name1" Converter="{StaticResource EmptyToUnsetConverter}" />
            <Binding Path="Name2" Converter="{StaticResource EmptyToUnsetConverter}" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

This would be more useful if you were working with different types of bindings or bindings from different sources and so on. For a collection of names, you might as well just wrap them with another property as others have shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) to get both values into the converter:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Name1" />
            <Binding Path="Name2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The "NameConverter" should be an `IMultiValueConverter`, which takes multiple values as inputs:

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name1 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(0) as string, 
            name2 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(1) as string;
        return name1 ?? name2;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

MultiBinding is a nifty approach, but in this case you may find it more convenient to simply add another read-only property "DisplayName" to your "test" class:

```
public class test
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get { return Name1 ?? Name2; } }
}
```

Comment: I'd use `ElementAtOrDefault(n)` instead of `Skip(n).FirstOrDefault()`. Looks cleaner IMO

Comment: @TimS. nice! I didn't know about "ElementAtOrDefault"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest solution would be to add in a custom property `DisplayName`, say, and just write code for it's `Get()`?